# Do we need both [forecasting] and [prediction] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I do not see a clear distinction between [forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting) and [prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) tags.

- Should they be made synonyms?
- Or should the distinction be made clearer (e.g. by expanding the currently very brief [description of the forecasting tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/forecasting/info) and/or editing the [description of the prediction tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction/info))?
- Or ... ?

Comment: Predictions can be about unknown past values; forecasting can't. Clarifying the tag excerpts / wikis may be appropriate, though.

Comment: It's funny that even though [forecasting] would seem me to a subset of [prediction], the former tag has almost twice as many threads as the latter one.

Comment: @amoeba, that need not be surprising as it seems natural to use specific in place of general tags. I do not use `time-series` tag when I post something specific only to ARIMA or GARCH, even though both are time series models.

Comment: As this is directly related to the newer Meta thread about wikis and that one is resolved, do you want to mark the answer here as accepted too?

Comment: @amoeba, thanks for the heads-up. Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, we need both. I think forecasting is more specifically about time-series data -- "What happens next?" Prediction the task of deploying a model to assess unseen data in some way. With prediction, there need not be any time-series component at all; you might just be interested in how well a model does against a holdout set of observations.

Support of this can be found in Cressie & Wikle *Statistics for Spatio-Temporal Data*, p. 17:

> Uncertainty in data, processes or parameters means that there will be uncertainty in conclusions. Statisticians call this drawing of conclusions in the presence of uncertainty, *statistical inference* (or just *inference*); in this book, inferences will be either *estimation* of fixed but unknown parameters, or *prediction* of unknown random quantities. (Notice that "forecasting," namely concluding something about the future, is a special case of "prediction.")

I've edited this description into the [forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting) and [prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) wikis.

Comment: I agree. Although I tend to enjoy fussing over definitions as an acceptable blood sport, to me the argument is intensely practical. Imagine abolishing either of these tags. That would be futile. There are many, many time series people who would feel deprived without "forecasting" and many, many others who would feel entirely uncomfortable without "prediction".

Comment: Fine. Then perhaps we should make the distinction between the two clearer? So far `forecasting` seems to be a subset of `prediction`. (I am making things a bit simpler than they are, but I want to highlight a point.)

Comment: I just read the tags. "Prediction is concerned with assessing the probability of unknown values from known values and inferred relationships." I don't think that matches prediction as widely used at all. Prediction is about predicting [sic] the unknown, but there need be no probability explicit. If I predict systolic blood pressure from body weight in some model, the prediction is (to me) just the fitted value. Some probability is at most implicit.

Comment: But in asserting that typically fitted and predicted are one and the same, I may be starting more hares and clashing with usages in particular fields of statistical science (to say nothing of machine learning).

Comment: Naturally I am not in denial about prediction intervals and so forth. But they are part of how prediction is often done, not an essential part of the definition.

Comment: @NickCox, "in asserting that typically fitted and predicted are one and the same, I may be starting more hares": indeed you are. [Here is your first hare.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207010000063)

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for the reference. My premise is that forecasting and prediction overlap but are not identical. The comment  cited is how I see the mundane practice at elementary or intermediate level of working with regression-like models. I tend to use fitted values and predicted values more or less interchangeably and find that in reading. I am sympathetic to anyone who wanted to introduce a precise distinction, but that would be flying in the face of much relaxed usage. This still leaves the Wiki text, which I find unsatisfactory, while being shy of trying to rewrite it.

Comment: @NickCox I just happened upon a definition in a textbook I am reading, and thought you might be interested.

Comment: I like it. Presumably "porceses" was a typo. If borrowing for Wiki, correct "either be" to "be either".